# Regex Patterns with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a script/program where I can find matching IP Addresses in two text files:

- One text file that contains a list of IP addresses (1.1.1.1)
- One text file that contains a list of subnets (1.1.1.0/28)

And I want to use regex and I'm not really sure how to do it.

Example:

```
import re


def check(fname1, fname2):
    f2 = open(fname2)
    f1 = open(fname1)
    pattern = ('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')

    for line in f1:
        p1 = re.match(pattern, line)
        out_p1 = p1.group(0)
        for item in f2:
            p2 = re.match(pattern, item)
            out_p2 = p2.group(0)
            if out_p1 in out_p2:
                print(line, item)
```

So I'm trying to match an IP address from the first text file with a subnet from the second text file.
Then I want to output the IP address with it's matching subnet.

Like so:

```
#IP      #Subnet
1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.0/28
8.8.10.5, 8.8.8.0/23
```

Comment: how prohibitive is it to pull both files into RAM before you search?

Comment: You want to find matches of lines in `F1` in lines of `F2`? What do you mean by `compare the patterns of the two files`.

Comment: Yeah I want to compare the lines of f1 and f2. But I have to cut the string to do so.

Comment: Finally, as a comment, think about what you have written in your code. You pull a match to `pattern` from `F1`, then you want to look for **that** match in `F2`, but your code looks for a match of `pattern` in `F2`

Comment: Please, if you want to add details, **edit** your question; don't add those details as comments.\

Comment: "But If I try to do:" (broken off because you pressed `Enter`). Please use [edit] to add all relevant information into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the pulling of lines of data from your two text files into program memory (simply `f1 = open(fname1, 'r').readlines()` for example), assume you have two lists of lines.

```
import re

f1 = ['1.1.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.35.192.1', 'some other line not desired']


f2 = ['1.1.1.0/28', '1.2.2.0/28', '192.168.1.1/8', 'some other line not desired']



def get_ips(text):
    # this will match on any string containing three octets
    pattern = re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
    out = []
    for row in text:
        if re.match(pattern, row):
            out.append(re.match(pattern, row).group(0))
    return out


def is_match(ip, s):
    # this will return true if ip matches what it finds in string s
    if ip in s:
        return True


def check(first, second):
    # First iterate over each IP found in the first file
    for ip in get_ips(first):
        # now check that against each subnet line in the second file
        for subnet in second:
            if is_match(ip, row):
                print('IP: {ip} matches subnet: {subnet}')
```

Note that I have tried to break up some of the functionality to separate concerns. You should be able to modify each function separately. This is assuming that you get your lines into some lists of strings. I also am not certain what you really want to match in `F2` so this should allow you to modify `is_match()` while leaving the other parts unaffected.

Good luck.

Comment: How would you print the full IP instead of the first three octets 1.1.1?

Comment: You only spec'd getting the first three octets in each line from `F1`, so you don't have that. You could either pull all the four octets from each line of `F1` and then modify `is_match()` to pull out the first three and test that for being in `s`, or you could build a dictionary in `get_ips()` with both the three and four octet match from each line, etc. There are different ways to skin a cat as they say....

Answer (score 1):

By running that nested loop, you're going to do a lot of unnecessary processing, it'd make more sense to append all of the matches from the first file into a list, then check against that list with the matches from the second file. This is an approximation of the process here using two local lists:

```
import re

input1 = ['1.1.1.1', '233.123.4.125']
input2 = ['1.1.1.1/123', '123.55.2.235/236']
pattern = ('^(\d{1,3}\.?){4}')
matchlist = []


for line in input1:
  p1 = re.match(pattern, line)
  matchlist.append(p1.group(0))

print(matchlist)

for item in input2:
  p2 = re.match(pattern, item)
  t = p2.group(0)
  if t in matchlist:
    print t
```